# How to get regex that tests for digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to test emailpatterns:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\d+\b@\b[a-zA-Z]+\d+)
```

It should test for numbers after the @ char:

```
john@mail2.com VALID
john2@mail.com VALID
john2@mail2.com VALID
jo2hn@mail.com VALID
john@m2.com VALID
john@mail.com INVALID
```

How can I make this regex work?

Comment: What's the regex back-end? Python, perl, grep???

Comment: You seem to know how to test for digits; what is the problem, then?

Comment: JavaScript it is

Comment: The `\b` won't be necessary because `@` is already a non-word character: you are already forcing the boundary.

Comment: the last `\d` shouldn't be there. It checks for number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not want to match a string that has no digit in it.

Use

```
^(?!\D*$)[\da-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z\d]+\.com$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r30tB9/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\D*$)` - the string cannot only contain non-digit chars (and cannot be empty - else, replace `*` with `+`)
- `[\da-zA-Z]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `@` -  a `@`
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `\.com`  - a `.com` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches any string that has a number before or after the @ sign.

```
\d[a-zA-Z]*@|@[a-zA-Z]*\d
```

Comment: I want to have numbers before the @ too

Comment: @bierhier - I made a modification to the regex to make the number before the @ sign optional. It might help if you add to your question a list of sample email addresses you expect to be matched.

Comment: @bierhier - I updated the answer to meet your new requirements.

Comment: @bierhier - I missed that you didn't want to match john@mail.com. I changed the regex to match inside any string that has a number before and/or after the @ sign. Perhaps that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain your destination rule.
Do you mean that you need the email contain at least one digit?

```
var rgx = /[a-z\d]+(?:(?<=\d.*)@|@(?=.*\d))[a-z\d]+\.com/i;

rgx.test('john@mail2.com'); //true
rgx.test('john2@mail.com'); //true
rgx.test('john2@mail2.com'); //true
rgx.test('jo2hn@mail.com'); //true
rgx.test('john@m2.com'); //true
rgx.test('john@mail.com'); //false
```

Comment: what if I want this to be valid: jo2hn@mail.com or john@m2.com?